# Doctrine 2 annotations and "var"

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Could someone tell me whats the meaning of "@var" in annotations configuration?

For example:

```
/**
 * @Column(type="string", length=20, unique=TRUE)
 * @var string
 */
protected $login;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It tells you what type of variable is it. Whether it's integer, string or an object, for example. It's used for auto-documentating processes

Comment: Does Doctrine itself use somehow the `@var` annotation or is it only for phpDoc purposes?

Answer (score 5):

This is an annotation used for automatic documentation generation with [phpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/). For @var see [their documentation](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.var.pkg.html).

Comment: This is a case of cobblers children, the first link tells us that the documentation for @var hasn't been written and the second one is 404.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot guarantee persistent links... But I can fix them.